# showing next tab bootstrap angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-router

i have a problem,if i click report tab or another tab. it will be back to login page. i want that if i click another tab, it's not go back to login page. is there any solution? this is my plunk

https://plnkr.co/edit/snDNgPEToZsIbXaHSWib?p=preview

here is my js file, thank you and sorry for bad english

```
var app = angular.module('coba', ['ngRoute']);

app.filter('coba', function() {
    return function(input, begin) {
        if (input) {
            begin = +begin;
            return input.slice(begin);
        }
        return [];
    }
});
app.filter('report', function() {
    return function(input, begin) {
        if (input) {
            begin = +begin;
            return input.slice(begin);
        }
        return [];
    }
});

app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) { 
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
          templateUrl: 'login.html',
          controller: 'logincont'
        })
        .when('/main', {
          templateUrl: 'mainmenu2.html'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);

app.run(function($rootScope,$route,$location){
       var unauthRoutes= [];
       console.log(unauthRoutes);
    angular.forEach($route.routes, function(route, path) {
        // push route onto unauthRoutes if it has a truthy allowUnauth value
        route.allowUnauth && (unauthRoutes.push(path));
    });

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, nextLoc, currentLoc) 
    {
        var atuhRoute= (-1 === unauthRoutes.indexOf($location.path()));

        if(atuhRoute && !$rootScope.loggedIn) {
            $location.path('/');
        }
    });
})

app.controller("logincont", ['$scope','$http','$window','$location','$rootScope',function($scope,$http,$window,$location,$rootScope){
$scope.login = function () {
      if ($scope.userid == 'rock' && $scope.pass == 'rock')
        {
          alert('Login Incorrect'); 
        }
        else
        {
          $rootScope.loggedIn = true;
          $location.path('/main');
          console.log('success');
        }
      };  

      }]);

app.controller("moncont", ['$scope','$http','$filter','$window','$location',function($scope,$http,$filter,$window,$location){
  $scope.logout = function(){
    $location.path('/logout');
  }
      }]);

app.controller("repcont", ['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
  $scope.logout = function(){
    $location.path('/logout');
      };

      }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Thing is, in your code, in the routes file, you donot have all the routse mentioned in your pluker

There is one route for `main`

```
.when('/main', {
          templateUrl: 'mainmenu2.html'
  })
```

Change, `#main` to `#!main` to make it work.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs navbar-ke-kanan" >
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#!login">Log Out</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#!main">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#!main">Report</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#!main">Monitoring</a></li>
  </ul>
```

[**Here is AN UPDATED PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/nZsMdAHtQYvLT9yzB1QS?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the working code - https://plnkr.co/edit/lYvMFO96IxpwfizjrUjy?p=preview

You should add code in script to handle routing to every route you have in your application. Example, if you wanna visit `/report` you should have the following -

```
.when('/main', {
  templateUrl: 'mainmenu2.html'
})
```

Similarly, update your links from `href="#report"` to `href="#!report"`

Hope this helps.

Comment: i've try, but if i click again to monitor again. it will be return to login page, thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

You have your links pointing to non-existing pages so they are calling `$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});`, which re-directs you back to the login screen because of `when('/', { templateUrl: 'login.html', ...`

Your links also need a proper hash-bang:

```
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#!/home">Log Out</a></li>
```

Updated from `#home` to `#!/home`

Now they can point to the right pages, as long those exist, so you need to modify your config:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) { 
     $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller: 'logincont'
     })
     .when('/main', {
        templateUrl: 'mainmenu2.html'
      })
     .when('/menu1', {
        templateUrl: 'menu1.html'
      })
     .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'home.html'
      })
     .when('/report', {
        templateUrl: 'report.html'
      })
      .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```